# Getting mouse movement input rather than the cursor position (C++)

Tags: c++, windows, console-application, mouse

I want to have my code read the movement of the mouse and act accordingly, for example, if you are moving your mouse up, you print `the mouse is moving up` in the console and sort of like that. (I am using Windows 10.)

The problem is, I could find a lot of articles that take the coordinates of the mouse cursor, but couldn't find one that deals with the real raw mouse input. The reason I want to do it this way is that when your cursor hits the border and cannot go further, the cursor position wouldn't change and the program won't recognize the mouse movement even though the mouse is "physically" moving. Another problem is that certain programs can "lock" your cursor to stay in a fixed position. For example, most FPS games do that.

Therefore, I wanted to get the raw input that the sensor of the mouse gives to the computer and utilize them instead of cursor position.

Comment: I am using windows 10.

Comment: If you are writing Windows applications, you must _surely_ have encountered the MSDN documentation at one point or another. This is usually one of the top hits when you search the internet for _"<the thing you want to achieve>"_ combined with a keyword like _"win32"_. Here's the top hit for [win32 mouse movement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/learnwin32/mouse-movement) as a starting point for you.

Comment: Some additional reading: [Keyboard and Mouse Input](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/_inputdev/), [Raw Input](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/inputdev/raw-input), [RAWMOUSE structure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/ns-winuser-rawmouse)

Comment: @paddy Thanks a lot, I'll definitely check those out!

Answer (score 0):

> Therefore, I wanted to get the raw input that the sensor of the mouse gives to the computer and utilize them instead of cursor position.

Use the [Raw Input API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/inputdev/raw-input) for that.  Call [`RegisterRawInputDevices()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-registerrawinputdevices) to register the target mouse device(s) you want to monitor (there could be multiple connected to the PC), and then handle [`WM_INPUT`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/inputdev/wm-input) messages containing the raw input data from the mouse(s).